# Can I use phpMyAdmin command line?

Tags: phpmyadmin

My ISP only accept PHP cron jobs.

Can I use phpMyAdmin command line?

Like: http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/export.php

or: http://myhosting.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=user_phpbb&passw=xxxxx

Thanks, Francisco

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  So that people can answer your question, could you provide an explanation of what you mean by "only accepts PHP cron jobs"?  What _don't_ they permit?  What are you trying to do with the phpMyAdmin command line.  These are some questions that you should ask yourself - to make a quality question it's best to put those types of things in your questions.  To learn more about Stack Overflow, visit the [About] page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There now is a phpmysql-cli (made as april fools joke, but functional)

See: https://github.com/fdev/phpmyadmin-cli

Comment: looks like it was made for old version of phpmyadmin (tried it with v.5 and it did not work for me)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) of your DBMS (Database Management System, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)) instead. It will be more secure, easier, faster and much more powerful than using phpmyadmin. See here for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html)

If, for some reasons, your hosting company only allows connections from localhost, and absolutely require you to use PHPMyAdmin, you should try making your own PHP scripts.